# Display text over image on hover

Tags: css

I am trying to display a text over an image and it works, but when I mouse over the text, it blinks!

[https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lhaje/](https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lhaje/1/)

html:

```
<a class="wrapper">
<img style="margin-top:50px;" 
src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg"
alt="" /></a>
```

css:

```
div.title {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -170px;
}

a.wrapper:hover + div {
    display: block;
}

<div class="title"><h1>TEXT HERE</h1></div>
```

please help me fix this.. maybe it's better to use a background image instead?

Answer (score 4):

It's blinking because your cursor is actually no longer hovering over the div, but instead its hovering over the div, thus the hover method is no longer triggered.

you could try the following css:

```
div.title:hover, a.wrapper:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

which will apply the hover when over the image, as well as over the div.
Updated version of your jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lhaje/7/

You could also use pointer-events to remove the problem:

```
a.wrapper:hover + div {
    display: block;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

However, it should be noted that this isn't supported in IE10 or before.

Comment: chrome, it blinks when you go mouse over text

Comment: It does indeed. my bad - updated answer to give you an actual answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be better with this

```css
.title {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -170px;
}

.wrap:hover div.title {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <a class="wrapper">
        <img style="margin-top:50px;" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div class="title"><h1>TEXT HERE</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to change the structure, wouldn't you be better off moving the title div inside the <A> tag, instead of adding a second div just to act as a wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

pointer-events: none;

Fixed your fiddle:

```
div.title {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -170px;
}

a.wrapper:hover + div {
    display: block;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lhaje/

Answer (score 0):

Solution changed HTML structure

For example

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/6k2Lhaje/2/)

HTML

```
<a class="wrapper">
<img style="margin-top:50px;" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="" />
<div class="title"><h1>TEXT HERE</h1></div></a>
```

CSS

```
div.title {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -170px;
}

a.wrapper:hover .title {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse doesn't hover the wrapper, when it is on the text.

Change your Css to that, so you display block too when you hover the text:

```
a.wrapper:hover + div.title,
div.title:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lhaje/10/

Answer (score 0):

the main issue of that blinking is that the Text you are hovering is OUTSIDE of the a tag which is targetet with the hover effekt.

A better way to approach this problem would be to put the text inside the container which contains the image. Then position the text absolute above the image.

Like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/zw8L4g7j/

```
<a class="wrapper">
    <h1>Text</h1>
<img style="margin-top:50px;" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="" />
</a>



h1{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:200px;
    top:150px;
}
a:hover h1{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it blinks because your `div.title` is on top of the `a.wrapper` without being its child element. So when you enter `div.title`, the browser considers that a `mouseleave` event for `a.wrapper` occured while the `hover` effect for `a.wrapper` is still active.

A better way make the desired effect would be:

1. Use a parent `div.wrapper` for `a` and give it a fixed size. This makes things easier as `a` have `display:inline` by default.
2. Make `div.title` a child of `a`. This makes the link 'visible' when `hover`. In yours the cursor does not change on `hover`.
3. Make `img` fit its parent with `width:100%`
4. Use`opacity:0` instead of `display:none`
5. Make `div.title` fill its parent with `height:100%` and `width:100%`. This way the `mouseenter` event for `hover` will match the one for the `img`
6. Set `position:absolute` on `div.title` and position it relatively from `div.wrapper` by setting `position:relative` on it.
7. Set `opacity:1` on `div.title:hover`

Here is a demo:

```css
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}
div img {
  width: 100%;
}
div.title {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
div.title:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg"/>
    <div class="title"><h1>TEXT HERE</h1></div>
   </a>
</div>
```

BONUS:

1. You can set `color:black` on `a` to ovewrite the default blue.
2. You can add `display:flex`, `align-items:center` and `justify-content:center` to `div.title` to center the content on the image
3. You can add `transition` to `div.title` and `div.title:hover`. This makes a smooth transition effect and you almost don`t see it if you hover fast enought.

[BONUS DEMO](http://codepen.io/guizo/pen/zojvra)

Answer (score 0):

**Display Text over Image, when hover Image.**

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="some-image.jpg">
    <p>SOME TEXT OVER IMAGE</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

#container img{
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    overflow: hidden;
}

#container p{
    visibility: hidden;

    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;

    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;

    z-index: 1;
}

#container:hover p{
    visibility: visible;
}
```